# open PDF files in Firefox

Tags: firefox

I have Firefox and It was working fine.
Recently , I cannot open PDF files even though I have a PDF tools . it start open it and then stuck ...
so I have to download all PDF files in order to have a look at .
can anyone explain me the problem ???
I have Firefox 25.0.1 and Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: What kind of PDF tool do you want to use? The integrated PDF viewer "pdf.js" is quite good, but there certainly are browser plug-ins from third-party providers.

Answer (score 0):

Try to download "adobe reader" or "viewPDF "from ubuntu software center.

Comment: I don't think this is an answer to the underlying problem, because the PDF viewer inside the browser has been working at an earlier time.